# How to access Pytest item outside a test function

Tags: python, pytest

I want to retrive pytest current running test item and then append my function running data into `item.user_properties`.

I tried to create `dummy` plugin and impl `pytest_runtest_protocol`, update running item in side the hook, then access item from plugin `from _pytest.config import get_plugin_manager`, `plugin_manager.get_plugin('dummy').current_running_item`
but it does not work, `get_plugin('dummy')` return `None`

How can I achive this or is there a better way?

```
# my_package/utl.py
from _pytest.config import get_plugin_manager
def my_requester(url):
    ...
    ...
    manager = get_plugin_manager()
    dummy = manager.get_plugin('dummy')
    item = dummy.current_item
    item.user_properties.append(('requested_url',url))
```

```
# conftest.py
import pytest
class Dummy:
    def __init__():
        self.current_item = None
    def pytest_runtest_protocol(self, item, nextitem):
        self.current_item = item

def pytest_configure(config):
    dummy_plugin = Dummy()
    config.pluginmanager.register(dummy_plugin,'dummy')
```

```
# test_demo.py
import pytest
from my_package.utl import my_requester


def test_a():
    ...
    my_requester('xxxx')

def test_b():
    ...
    my_requester('yyy')
```

Comment: `pytest_runtest_protocol` must be a function, not a method - it will not be found this way.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution
just use Singleton pattern, set test item to a singleton object property, and append function running data to that property